# Подсказки для Bootstrap в Visual Studio Code

Tags: bootstrap, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Возникла проблема, точнее неудобство в использовании Bootstrap'a в Visual Studio Code
Вкратце проблема такая - не выдает автодополнения адекватно, HTML, CSS , JS все ок, но Bootstrap только через <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (на маке, на винде незнаю как).

Пошерстив гугл нашел решения только с помощью как раз таки <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, есть ли решения без такого шортката? Просто чтобы выдавались подсказки как обычно это происходит с HTML, CSS , JS.

P.S: попробовал с Sublime Text, там все с этим ок, но незнаю почему сам Sublime Text лично для меня неудобен, Visual Studio Code больше нравится поэтому и ищу решения для него.
Заранее спасибо за подсказки, если таковые будут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это расширение, должно работать.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thekalinga.bootstrap4-vscode

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уже попробовал webstorm) он понравился, много не нужного для меня пока что , так как только учусь, но мне удобно. Но все равно спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Установите расширение HTML CSS Support.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css

Answer (score 0):

Если у тебя стоит расширение "IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML".
Нужно его перезапустить, т.е. отключить, при этом VSC нужно перезагрузить, а потом включить снова. Мне помогло.